# External Bug Tracker Configuration - Redmine - How to configure It

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I have read - [Configure external bug trackers](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#configure-external-bug-trackers)
And - [module-tcms.issuetracker.types](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.issuetracker.types.html#module-tcms.issuetracker.types)

And used configuration - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4da7.png)
But it doesnt works, Is there a working example?

Comment: Version of KiwiTCMS you are using?

Comment: Are you sure "http://192.168.10.92/readmine" is the correct API URL ? Have you tried only the address without the path suffix?   How do you know it doesn't work, what are your steps to reproduce?  Can you get a traceback ? FYI follow this issue https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/97 to know when we add a health check functionality.

Comment: @Prome - I am using last kiwi ver V7.1.

Comment: @AlexanderTodorov - took the rest configuration from [here](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api)